# PHP How to see if someone accepted the Terms of Service

Tags: php, html, service

I have a terms of service text and whenever someone presses "Accept" it detects it and directs it to the next step. Although people CAN get to the next step without accepting the Terms of Service button.

Now my question: How can I code it so that when people manually go to the step page it displays a message that they have to accept the Terms of Service first?

Kind Regards,
Ixecube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using a session variable, or to a lesser extent, a cookie. When the form is POST'ed - set a session variable using $_SESSION and check for existence of that variable when they try to access the site.

This would also require use of sessions on your site. I would suggest reading up on Sessions at http://www.php.net.

Comment: Here is the link: http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

Pay careful attention to this function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: Good luck! I hope this helps you out

Comment: I have an index.php page which needs to have the session_start() attribute on it, right?

Now i have a form on the index.php page with a action="accept.php" which contains the php code to see if people pressed the "Agree" button. When they do they get redirected to the step1.php page.

My question is where do I have to put the session_start() attribute?

Comment: You will need to put the session_start() on all pages that you want to maintain session data across. Best bet is to have an include file that contains that, along with any logic that will check to see if they are allowed to access that resource.

Comment: Make sure you accept this answer if it works for you :)

Comment: (I hope you still read this) I put an "if" in the accept.php which checks if the person accepted the ToS or not. And it said this:

if ($termsofservice == 'yes')

What do I need to put in the forms? name="termsofservice" ? or id="termsofservice" or do I have to put it in the form like this? <form name="termsofservice">?

Im kinda confused

Comment: In your index.php you will have a form, with some named form elements. That form will post to accept.php. In the accept.php file, you will have a $_POST variable which will contain the POST'ed form elements from index.php. Check to make sure the value that they accepted is there. If it is, set the session variable and allow them to continue.

Comment: Alright, but what do I have to choose for the form?
This: name="yes"
Or: value="yes"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7239/discussion-between-barry-chapman-and-ixecube)